# My character keeps rolling when I press play in unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

My 2D character keeps rolling and falls to the ground

please tell me a good combination of colliders, so that it wont roll or fall during moving and jumping.
Also my character has only one part.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgMaG.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try to select "Rigidbody 2D" component on character GameObject (or add this component if You haven't one), then select Rigidbody2D>Constraints>Freeze Rotation>Z -> check box (freeze rotation around Z-axis).

Maybe You should set Rigidbody2D>Gravity Scale -> 0 (set to zero), if You already don't do this, to prevent character falling if You don't need this feature.